Can I drywall directly over rigid foam insulation
If I apply rigid foam insulation directly over a wall and tape the joints, can I drywall directly over that?  The wall is a combination of brick and 2x4.  It was previously for an exterior room that will now be closed off and interior.
The foam insulation is listed as vapor retardant so I believe that to mean that I can use it as a vapor barrier.

Yes you can, but a pic of the wall will help us better inform you.

What is the spacing between the 2x4s?

I have an existing brick wall that is being closed in with windows and 2x4 framing.  The 2x4 framing is running flush to the brick, so I was thinking that rather than make the wall even thicker, just run rigid foam insulation over the brick and 2x4 and then drywall.  The 2x4 is framed every 16-in on center.

Does the brick still have a drying path available?  "If it doesn't dry, it dies"

The top part of the wall will be framed in and sided.  If water were to get behind the siding, rain screen, rigid foam, and housewrap and metal flashing, then it could conceivably get behind the brick wall where on the other side the rigid foam insulation and then drywall is.  Even if I frame that in, the same issue would apply.  If water gets on that side of the brick, then it would be trapped between the brick and vapor barrier.  For that to happen though, a lot of things would need to happen, perhaps there is a leak in the roof or I use a pressure washer.
